# Why use PDO's rowCount() if I can just use PHP's count()?

Tags: php

So in PHP, there's PDO to fetch things from a database. Now I see a bunch of `$stmt->rowCount()` calls in the code I'm working with. Why not just fetch the result array and throw a PHP `count()` over the result to fetch the row count? Wouldn't this make PDO's `rowCount()` obsolete?

Comment: A `SELECT COUNT` query will be much, much faster than actually loading all the rows and count them.

Comment: That makes for all the more reason for PDO's `rowCount()` to be obsolete.

Comment: `rowCount()` is often less useful and slower than a simple `SELECT COUNT()` query. It's there for completeness sake, because PDO may be used for a wide variety of DBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You being able to select the count of rows directly aside, the only reason is abstraction.

By using the `rowCount` method over directly calling `count` on retireved data, you move the logic to the PDO driver and are independent on the implementation.

Perhaps sometime in the future there will be a better function to count rows, faster, taking less resources, but still having the same API as the old one, could be called `counti`, where `i` stands for improved, and the PDO creators decide to use it.

If you counted all the rows yourself, you are now forced to change the call from `count` to `counti` in your entire codebase. But if you used the `rowCount` method instead, you could only install the new PDO version and be set.

In most cases, however, if the only thing you want is the count of rows, `SELECT COUNT` is the way to go.